# Como remover 2 digitos de cada item da lista?

Tags: java, array, lista, groovy

Tenho uma lista/array:

```
var lista['01.um','02.dois','03.tres']
```

preciso criar uma nova lista assim:

```
lista['01','02','03']
```

Sei pouco de Groovy e Java,
qual é o caminho correto para criar a lista?

Answer (score 6):

Estou supondo que você possui um *array* de String e que está buscando obter os dois primeiros caracteres. Você não mencionou se eles devem ter tipo inteiro na segunda lista, então estou considerando que a segunda lista também será de strings. Se precisar que sejam inteiros, use [`Integer#parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-).

Você pode usar [`String#substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) para "cortar" os dois primeiros caracteres de cada string. Ou então pode usar o ponto como delimitador para o método [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), quebrando a string em um *array* e obtendo seu primeiro índice.

Não conheço muito bem Groovy mas arrisquei uma resposta. Pode ser que tenham formas mais eficientes das que tentei aqui.

### Java

```
String[] array = {"01.um", "02.dois", "03.tres"};

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    array[i] = array[i].substring(0, 2);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
// [01, 02, 03]
```

#### # [resultado](https://ideone.com/9V86VY)

```
String[] array = {"01.um", "02.dois", "03.tres"};

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    array[i] = array[i].split("\\.")[0];

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
// [01, 02, 03]
```

#### # [resultado](https://ideone.com/eRMfFo)

---

### Groovy

```
lista = ['01.um', '02.dois', '03.tres']

for(i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++)
    lista[i] = lista[i].substring(0,2)

println lista
// [01, 02, 03]
```

#### # [resultado](https://ideone.com/axNrsU)

```
lista = ['01.um', '02.dois', '03.tres']

for(i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++)
    lista[i] = lista[i].tokenize('.')[0]

println lista
// [01, 02, 03]
```

#### # [resultado](https://ideone.com/TkrV4e)

Answer (score 4):

Ficou assim:

```
String[] arrayTipos= tiposSelecionados;

for(int i = 0; i < arrayTipos.length; i++)
    arrayTipos[i] = arrayTipos[i].substring(0, 2);

String[] consulta= "SELECT telas FROM interfaceUsuario WHERE tipo in(" + Arrays.toString(arrayServicos) +")";

return consulta;
```

Obrigada!

Answer (score 3):

Você não pode remover elementos de um básico array no Java,tente `Collections` e `ArrayList` para você pode remover de forma correta.

Para lhe ajudar,peguei seu array e criei um novo com ArrayList,para criar e deletar o que você deseja.

**Exemplo do seu código com ArrayList :**

```
import java.util.*;

            String[] array = new String[] { "01.um", "02.dois", "03.tres" };

    System.out.println("Anterior : " + Arrays.toString(array));

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
    list.removeAll(Arrays.asList("01.um"));
    list.removeAll(Arrays.asList("02.dois"));
    list.removeAll(Arrays.asList("03.tres"));
    list.add("01");
    list.add("02");
    list.add("03");
    array = list.toArray(array);

    System.out.println("Atual : " + Arrays.toString(array));
```

Já testei e funciona perfeitamente,caso tiver mais dúvidas dê uma olhada nas seguintes documentações :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/arraylist/arraylist-in-java-example-how-to-use-arraylist/

Answer (score 2):

Em Groovy:

```
def lista = ['01.um','02.dois','03.tres']
```

**Opção 1 (se os números forem formados sempre por dois dígitos):**

```
def novaLista = lista.collect {it.take(2)}
def novaLista = lista*.take(2) //versao compacta
```

**Opção 2 (os números são formados por uma quantidade de dígitos arbitrária, mas sempre existe o "." para separá-los):**

```
def novaLista = lista.collect {it.tokenize(".").first()}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/swfVHy).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar split() ou tokenize() para quebrar a string em partes. Depois disso, podes usar collect para criar a nova lista.

```
def lista = ['01.um', '02.dois', '03.tres']

def novaLista1 = lista.collect { it.split(/\./)[0] }
def novaLista2 = lista.collect { it.tokenize('.')[0] }

println novaLista1 // => [01, 02, 03]
println novaLista1.class.name // java.util.ArrayList
println novaLista2 // => [01, 02, 03]
println novaLista2.class.name // java.util.ArrayList
```

O método split é dado uma expressão regular para achar o ponto (literal). Já o tokenize funciona só com uma string dentro de aspas, sem ter que escapar o ponto.

Embora o resultado seja o mesmo nas duas escolhas acima, o produto de `split()` é uma array de String (`String[]`) e o resultado de `tokenize()` é uma `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta do @Renan, segue uma das formas do java utilizando a versão 8:

```
List<String> lista = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"01.um", "02.dois", "03.tres"});

List<String> listaModificada = lista.stream()
    .map(item -> item.substring(0, 2))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(listaModificada);
```

Obs: poderia ter usado static import para o código ficar mais enxuto.